# SQLAlchemy one-to-many relationship (Single table with join table)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have db that I cannot modify, it has two tables 'people' and 'relation'. The table 'people' has names, ids and the column parent (yes/no). The table 'relation' contains a foreign key 'people.id' for parent and a 'people.id' for its child. I want to join columns in the people table so I can

```
People.query.filter_by(id='id of the parent')
```

to get the name of the parent and it's childs. This is my code:

```
class People(db.model):  
    __tablename__ = 'people'
    id = db.Column(db.integer(), primary_key=True
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    parent = db.Column(db.Integer()) ##0 for no 1 for yes
    parent_id=db.relationship('Link',backref=db.backref('Link.parent_id')  

class Link(db.Model):
    _tablename__ = 'link'
    parent_id=db.Column(db.Integer(),db.ForeignKey('people.id'),primary_key=True)
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('people.id'), primary_key=True)
    dateofbirth = db.Column(db.Integer())
```

SQLAlchemy tells me:

```
ArgumentError: relationship 'parent_id' expects a class or a mapper argument (received: <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Table'>)
```

Excuse me if I messed up, but it's my first question here (and also the first steps with SQLAlchemy)

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would want to set up the foreign key and backref in the same table, like this:

```
class Link(db.Model):
    _tablename__ = 'link'
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer(),db.ForeignKey('people.id'),primary_key=True)
    parent = db.relationship('People', backref='links')
```

Now you can access each Link entries parent via Link.parent, and you can get a list of each People entries links via People.links (assuming this is a one-to-many relationship).

Also, if People.parent is supposed to represent a boolean value then:

1.) you should follow the standard naming convention and call it something like `is_parent`

2.) you should declare People.parent as a db.Boolean type, not a db.Integer. In most (probably all) database implementations, using booleans instead of integers (when appropriate) is more memory efficient.

I hope this helped.